# Limit points and reciprocals

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that there are no reciprocals of positive integers between consecutive reciprocals of positive integers.

I started by contradiction:

Assume there are no integers between $n$ and $n+1$.

Suppose $\dfrac1{n+1}<\dfrac1m<\dfrac1n$ where $m$ is an integer

I got down to

$$n<\frac{n(n+1)}m<n+1$$

This would be fine if I knew $\dfrac{n(n+1)}m$ was an integer, because then it would be a contradiction.

So I'm stuck. Any suggestions?

Comment: suggestion: Apply the L. C. M (i.e. n.m.(n+1)) to the denominators of the three fractions so that they can be compared on the same ground. From which, find the contradiction.

Comment: right, i also tried that, i got nm<n(n+1)<nm+m ...but nm and nm+m aren't consecutive.

Comment: am i not seeing it?

Comment: break nm<n(n+1)<nm+m into  "nm<n(n+1)" and "n(n+1)<nm+m". eventually, should get  n<m<n+1, which is a contradiction.

Comment: okay so , "nm<n(n+1)' reduces to "m<n+1". "n(n+1)<nm+m" reduces to "n<m" . Then putting it together I get, n<m<n+1, which contradicts the assumptions. Is that okay to break it up and put it back together though?

Comment: Yes. Definitely.

Comment: you were great help. I've been staring at this for hours .

Answer (score 0):

You started with $  (1/n+1)<(1/m)<(1/n)$. Do you know what happens to an inequality when you take the reciprocal of all the terms there?

Comment: Oh. are you suggesting to take the reciprocal of those terms? I will try that.